# Oracle: Procedure to Update rows, and the return the updated rows in sys_refcursor

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql, oracle11g, sys-refcursor

I want to do something like

update example_table
set field1=xx
where field2=someValue;

(here I want to open a sys_refcursor) with only the updated rows and return it.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

One way is to add a column to your table (f.e. `status varchar(1) default '-'`) and if updated, set status 'U', inserted -'I' etc...
Then You can just do select on this rows or whatever You want (Bulk Collect for example).